# IE set focus issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am facing problem of setting focus to text box in IE and the page scenario is as below.

having one text box and button. on page load text box is having focus set, then when i enter some int value it search for that number in table and add record to Repeater and update Repeater, everything is in update panel. first time when i enter value it sets focus correctly but for next consecutive hits it does not set focus to text box also the page focus is also out.

i am using enter button to submit number.
i tried all below options but no luck yet.Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

```
1. option => Page.SetFocus(txtOrdertoAdd.ClientID);
2. option => txtOrdertoAdd.Focus();
3. option => Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", "SetFocus(" + txtOrdertoAdd.ClientID + ");</script>");
4. option => ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "selectAndFocus", "$get('" + txtOrdertoAdd.ClientID + "').focus();", true);
```

you can check below screen how the page looks like. this everything is under update panel.

[image]

Comment: is there any one who knows the crack?

Comment: can you share your page_load code please? or more precisely.. where do you write the above options?

Comment: @SoftSan- i wrote this option on button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
sm.SetFocus(txtOrdertoAdd);
```

in your `Button_Click` event.

Comment: @SoftSan- i tried above option, but no luck. but thanks for your effort.

Comment: @rahul.deshmukh Try the same in your Page_Load event.